# Parsing dateTime in perl correct to micro/nano seconds

Tags: perl, datetime

Im looking for a perl module which takes a date string like this "Nov 23 10:42:31.808381" and its format something like "%b %d ...." this and get me a dateTime object/or print it into another format specified in the same way. Time::Piece doesnt have resolution upto nano seconds. Is there any module which will help me? 
Im using perl 5.8 (this doesnt have named backreferences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) has support for microseconds and nanoseconds.

Your format is slightly strange as it doesn't include a year. I've added one you make this demo code work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%6N',
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $string = 'Nov 23 2010 10:42:31.808381';

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($string);

print $dt->microsecond;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Nov 23 10:42:31.808381" -- is microseconds, not nanoseconds

If you need microseconds, you must use Time::HiRes; module and gettimeofday method in it.

Comment: Ya currently it is microseconds but I'will need for nano seconds too.

Comment: perl is not enougth fast even for microseconds resolution. and i don't understand, why you need nanoseconds.

Comment: Example: perl -e 'use Time::HiRes qw/nanosleep gettimeofday/; $a=gettimeofday();nanosleep(1);$b=gettimeofday(); print $b-$a;'
6.19888305664062e-05

Comment: I want to convert between dateTimeFormats where date is given precise upto nano seconds. The format has to be configurable too.