# Parse date String to milliseconds and vice versa

Tags: perl, datetime

I have following date in string format and I need to convert it to milliseconds using a Perl script. I have tried to convert it using `DateTime::Format::Strptime` and it returns 0 after convert to millisecond.

Date String : 01-13-15:14.16

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%m-%d-%y:%H.%M',
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime("01-13-15:14.16");

print $dt->millisecond."\n";
```

How can I convert datetime to milliseconds

Comment: that doesn't convert to milliseconds, it just returns the millisecond fraction of the time, which is 0.
Please explain better what you wish to achieve here, and we will be able to help you

Comment: I want to convert date string into milliseconds. this is what I tried to do after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl) and this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254464/parsing-datetime-in-perl-correct-to-micro-nano-seconds) examples. without the millisecond part it returns datetime as `2015-01-13T14:16:00`

Comment: You are parsing a datetime with no milliseconds set, therefore you will have 0 milliseconds to return. Any resolution higher than the one you pass in will result in zeros (it doesn't just make stuff up out of thin air)

It's still not clear what you want out of this. If you want to convert the datetime into seconds since the epoch, use that.

`print sprintf("%f", $dt->epoch + $dt->millisecond);`

Comment: this worked. I needed to convert my String date to milliseconds. can you add it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidK-J: The expression `$dt->epoch + $dt->millisecond` makes no sense because `epoch` is in seconds while `millisecond` is in, well, milliseconds. However, since `millisecond` is always zero there is no point in adding it, and it sounds like what the OP really wants is just `$dt->epoch`.

Comment: @Borodin, `$dt->epoch * 1000 + $dt->millisecond` (which is the same as just `$dt->epoch * 1000` in this case) would make sense, though, and would be consistent with JS timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's likely that what you want is not milliseconds but `epoch`, which is the number of *seconds* since January 1 1970. Your date-time format has neither seconds nor milliseconds, so both of these fields will be reported as zero, and if you *really* want milliseconds then you can simply multiply the `epoch` by 1000.

It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%m-%d-%y:%H.%M',
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime('01-13-15:14.16');
say $dt->epoch;
```

**output**

```
1421158560
```

However, the `DateTime` module is enormous and slow, and there is a better solution in the core module [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece), which would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime('01-13-15:14.16', '%m-%d-%y:%H.%M');
say $dt->epoch;
```

**output**

```
1421158560
```

Comment: thank you. I'll modify my script to use `Time::Piece` instead of `DateTime`

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to convert a date to milliseconds. A date is a point in time. Milliseconds measure a duration.

The only way your question makes sense is if we assume you mean "how many milliseconds are there between my given date/time and some other fixed date/time". Because of the way that Unix measures time, let's assume that the fixed date/time you're measuring from is the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

You get the number of seconds since the epoch from a DateTime object with the `epoch()` method.

```
say $dt->epoch;
```

To get the number of milliseconds, just multiply that by a thousand.

```
say 1000 * $dt->epoch;
```

Your current timestamp doesn't include milliseconds. If you change to parsing strings that include them, then you can add that value on too.

```
say $dt->milliseconds + (1000 * $dt->epoch);
```

Comment: I think you mean `say 1000 * $dt->epoch + $dt->millisecond`

Answer (score 1):

Adding my comment as an answer:

If you want to convert the datetime value into seconds since the epoch, try one of these:

```
print sprintf("%f", $dt->epoch + ($dt->millisecond/1000));
print sprintf("%s.%s", $dt->epoch, $dt->millisecond);
```

(My original comment did not account for millisecond being an integer)

Similar for the values in milliseconds, rather than seconds.millis:

```
print sprintf("%d", ($dt->epoch * 1000) + $dt->millisecond);
print sprintf("%d%04d", $dt->epoch, $dt->millisecond);
```

Remember, that if you don't supply DateTime with a value containing milliseconds (or higher resolution), the value will simply be zero.